# How can I get my enemies on my level in Borderlands 2

Tags: borderlands-2

In Borderlands 2 all the enemies in the dust are level 30-35 and I'm level 40. Same with Sanctuary and basically everywhere else. I can't level up because I only get 1 XP, I don't get any good new weapons because they're 5-10 behind what I have, I also can't buy any weps for the same reason, and all the quests are really easy and boring because the highest level quest in the game that isn't a level 50 boss in level 34, and I did it. I have beaten the game on normal mode and I have started a game on true vault hunter mode but I'm still on the southern shelf.

Comment: The story quests eventually lead you to level 50 enemies. Do those.

Comment: The asker successfully entered TVHM, so yes, this is a duplicate.